# What's the command to find out version of gcc is used inside a conda virtual environment?

Tags: python, gcc, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I have a program to be compiled in which I need to have `gcc`.

However, when a `python 2.7` virtual `conda` enviornment being installed, it needs `gcc`. So I believe I don't have to install `gcc` package seperately inside the enviornment. Is this true? And how do I actually see this?

Furthermore, gcc has already been installed in the ***system*** itself. I do not want the program to use this system `gcc` when it's compiling but to use the `gcc` version which is inside the enviornment. How do I actually test this? Thanks in advance!

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267201/how-to-install-gcc-in-virtualenv) discussion might be useful.

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057646/python-shows-wrong-gcc-version) post
"If you download python binaries, it's already compiled and doesn't use your gcc"

So to reprase my question, can we use the gcc inside the virtual to compile the program? or do I have to install gcc inside the env?

```
     (yourenvname) ~$gcc -v
        Using built-in specs.
        COLLECT_GCC=gcc
        COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
        OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
        OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
        Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
        Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix    
gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 


(yourenvname) ~$python
Python 2.7.16 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 14 2019, 21:00:58) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: `os.system("gcc --version")`???

Comment: Hi xenoid: This command  raises an error. (yourenvname) ~$import os
(yourenvname) ~$os.system("gcc --version")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"gcc --version"' `I have checked the gcc version inside and outside the env                     
`(yourenvname) ~$which gcc`
`home/jen/miniconda2/yes/envs/yourenvname/bin/gcc`
`~$which gcc`
`/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: I think as I have edited in the main question, python only uses gcc to compile it and after that we cannot use it inside the env to compile another program. Could someone confirm this?

Comment: I forgot to open python in my first comment`>>> import os
>>> os.system("gcc --version")
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u2) 4.9.2
0`

Comment: So this should answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'd like to know if I could use `[GCC 7.3.0]` (this GCC is the one which python uses to compile the binary) to compile my program inside the virtualenv or do I have to install gcc inside the virtualenv?.

Comment: @Jenny Did you get the answer to this question?